# Image not showing in Ionic React

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I want to show a .svg image which is in the assets directory in my `src` directory.

Here is a glimpse of the folder structure -

[image]

I want to get the `balloons.svg` from the `Register.tsx`.
I am using the `IonImg` element and have tried directories like `../assets/balloons.svg` as source but they doesn't seem to work.

Note: The image appears properly if I use an image URL as source.

Comment: `img src="/assets/balloons.svg" alt="logo"  className={'logo'}/>` try This.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked :(

Comment: Try using simple html `<img src="you-imgr-path"/>` dont use `Ion-img`

Comment: Tried it with `img` tag but that too didn't worked

Answer (score 2):

The svg needs to be imported into the Register.tsx file:

```
import Balloons from '../assets/balloons.svg';
```

And then set the src attribute to the import:

```
<IonImg src={Balloons} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend locate using "require" in Ionic react.

So try:

```
require("../assets/balloons.svg")
```

like:

```
<IonImg src={require("../assets/balloons.svg")} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your src in Ion React App will be like this code to lode the img ..

```
<IonImg src="/assets/imgs/image.JPG"></IonImg>
```

with out src point **../** like

```
<IonImg src="**../**public/assest/imgs/image.JPG"></IonImg>
```